# Add default value when on_delete triggers with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a way to nullify column when referenced column is removing through migration:

`add_foreign_key :todo_lists, :user_id, on_delete :nullify`

Is there a way to give default value instead of nullify a column?

Comment: Not through `add_foreign_key` but its possible to create database triggers with raw SQL. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html.

Comment: It is not neccessary through `add_foreign_key`. I want to implement it through migration.

Comment: Yes. You would have to do it with raw sql in a migration as per the comment above. If the question is if Rails has a built in way. Then no.

Comment: You could also implement a delete hook.  I know that's not a migration.

Comment: This is really more of a SQL question than Rails, since you are trying to implement the trigger on the DB level. However, just googling I found a gem that looks like it could be useful https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger